# Relative div height with 100%

Tags: html, css, alignment

How can set the height of the first column to the second column and the scrollbar?

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}

body {
  background-color: #F4F5F9;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.menu-right {
  min-height: 100%;
  background: red;
  width: 20px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  direction: rtl;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div style="height:100%">
  <div class="menu-right">
    2
  </div>

  <div class="menu-right">
    sdsdsds
    <br /> sdsdsds
    <br /> . . //something such as sdsdsds . .
  </div>
</div>
```

The output is as below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of *floating* to the right, you can use a *row-reverse* flexbox as your wrapper element. The default `align-items: stretch` behavior of flexbox will *stretch and match* the heights - see demo below:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #F4F5F9;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.wrapper>div {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  direction: rtl;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="menu-left">
    sdsdsds
    <br /> sdsdsds
    <br /> sdsdsds
    <br /> sdsdsds
    <br /> sdsdsds
    <br /> sdsdsds
    <br /> sdsdsds
    <br /> sdsdsds
    <br /> sdsdsds
  </div>
  <div class="menu-right">
    sdsdsds
    <br /> sdsdsds
    <br /> sdsdsds
    <br /> sdsdsds
    <br /> sdsdsds
    <br /> sdsdsds
    <br /> sdsdsds
    <br /> sdsdsds
    <br /> sdsdsds
    <br /> sdsdsds
    <br /> sdsdsds
    <br /> sdsdsds
    <br /> sdsdsds
    <br /> sdsdsds
    <br /> sdsdsds
    <br /> sdsdsds
    <br /> sdsdsds
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In the first image, there are two columns, I want to increase the height of the first column, which is "2", to the height of the second column. You have used overflow-y: scroll, which scrolled the second column, I want to set the first column and the second column to the page scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **flex box** instead of `float`. add a class in your outer div as `.container`, set the display property of the `.container` to `flex` and `align-items: stretch`

```css
body,html{height:100%;width:100%}
body{background-color:#F4F5F9;;font-size:11px}


.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.menu-right {
  min-height: 100%;
  background: red;
  width: 20px;
  position: relative;
  direction: rtl;
  margin-left: 10px;
  flex: 0 0 20px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="height:100%">
    <div class="menu-right">
      2
    </div>

    <div class="menu-right">
      sdsdsds
      <br />
      sdsdsds
      <br />
       .
       .
       //something such as sdsdsds
       .
       .
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: not work, with few br and sdsdsds the red column will not continue

Answer (score 0):

add second right div style `overflow-y:scroll` and `max-height:100%`

```css
body,html{height:100%;width:100%}
body{background-color:#F4F5F9;;font-size:11px}
.menu-right {
  min-height: 100%;
  background: red;
  width: 20px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  direction: rtl;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 10px;
  
}
```

```html
<div style="height:100%">
    <div class="menu-right">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="menu-right" style="overflow-y:scroll; max-height:100%">
      sdsdsds
      <br />
      sdsdsds
      <br />
       .
       .
       //something such as sdsdsds
       .
       .
      </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Does not work, with few br and sdsdsds the red column will not continue

Comment: I actually do not understand what you want please be specific. In your example in the first div there is "2" number and the column still continue. do you want to fit context and also when its more scroll?

Comment: In the first image, there are two columns, I want to increase the height of the first column, which is "2", to the height of the second column. You have used overflow-y: scroll, which scrolled the second column, I want to set the first column and the second column to the page scroll bar.

Comment: look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_equal_height)